# Is there another function than fig.show() to show a figure?

Tags: python, savefig

I'm  currently trying to learn how to built a map on global mapping tool (pygmt), but whenever I try `fig.show()` nothing happens. I tried to change graphic backend in tools preferences. The code works because when I use `fig.savefig('myfig.png')` I have the picture. I'm using spyder 4, on windows 10. I want to mention that `tkinter` doesn't work either (spyder crashes). And I can't try it on jupyter because I can't find the gmt kernel on jupyter.

the code:

```
import pygmt as gmt 

fig = gmt.Figure() 
fig.coast(shorelines="1/0.5p", region=[-180, 180, -60, 60], projection="M10i") 

fig.show() 
fig.savefig('gmttest.png')
```

Comment: please provide your code to help.

Comment: Here's the code :

Comment: import pygmt as gmt
fig = gmt.Figure()
fig.coast(shorelines="1/0.5p", region=[-180, 180, -60, 60], projection="M10i")
fig.show()
fig.savefig('gmttest.png')

Comment: Have you checked in plot winodw of spyder. Plots and figures are shown in plot window of spyder.

Comment: Yes I checked nothing appears in the plot window...